# Why does one function not wait for Promise.all() to resolve in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, promise, async-await

I have a simple form that allows files uploads to take place.

```
<form @submit.prevent="sendForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input multiple ref="PostFiles" name="PostFiles" type="file" @change="selectFile('add')">
  <!-- other fields here -->
  <button type="submit" name="Send" value="Send"></button>
</form>
```

1. The `selectFile()` method invokes the `uploadFile()` method to sends the files selected by the user to the server using `axios.post()` requests.
2. If the user decides to submit the form while an upload is still
   taking place, then it needs to `await` for `selectFile()` to finish
   before submitting.

This is what `selectFile()` does which works fine. It awaits for `uploadFile()` to resolve and then I get a success message in the console once all uploads are done:

```
async selectFile(action) {
  if (action === 'add') {
    // It adds the files to the array this.Form.PostFiles
    let PostFiles = this.$refs.PostFiles.files;
    if (this.Form.PostFiles == null || this.Form.PostFiles.length === 0) {
      this.Form.PostFiles = [...this.Form.PostFiles, ...PostFiles].map(file => { //returns a new array with the file object and metainfo object
        return [
          file, {
            originalFilename: file.name,
            uploadedFilename: "",
            size: file.size,
            type: file.type,
            isUploading: false,
            isUploaded: false,
            uploadProgress: 0,
            previewImgSrc: URL.createObjectURL(file)

          }
        ]
      });
    } else {
      PostFiles = Array.from(PostFiles).map(file => {
        return [
          file, {
            originalFilename: file.name,
            uploadedFilename: "",
            size: file.size,
            type: file.type,
            isUploading: false,
            isUploaded: false,
            uploadProgress: 0,
            previewImgSrc: URL.createObjectURL(file)
          }
        ]
      });
      this.Form.PostFiles.push(...PostFiles);

    }
  }

  try {
    return Promise.all(
        this.Form.PostFiles.map(async (file, i) => {
          const File = file[0];
          if (this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].isUploaded == false &&
            this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].isUploading == false) {
            await this.uploadFile({File: File, FileIndex: i});
          }
        })
      )
      .then(result => {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded all files")
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

The `uploadFile()` method uploads the files using `axios` like such:

```
async uploadFile({ File, FileIndex }) {
  const FormFile = new FormData();
  FormFile.append("UploadFile", File);

 this.Form.PostFiles[FileIndex][1].isUploading = true;

  return this.$axios.post('/api/post', FormFile)
     .then(response => {
       this.Form.PostFiles[FileIndex][1].isUploading = false;
       this.Form.PostFiles[FileIndex][1].isUploaded = true;
     }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
     })
```

So, here is where the problem occurs. If the user hits the submit button for the form while uploads are still taking place then the `sendForm()` method is not waiting for `selectFile()` to resolve all promises before submitting the file:

```
async sendForm() {
const FormBody = new FormData();
FormBody.append("PostTitle", this.Form.PostTitle);
FormBody.append("PostDescription", this.Form.PostDescription);
  try {
    await this.selectFile();
    this.$axios.post('/api/post', FormBody).then(response => {
      console.log("Form submitted");
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response.data.error)
    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I get a message in the console saying "Form submitted" even though there may be 3 uploads still in progress. It seems to print "Form submitted" soon after the first upload has completed. Why is it not awaiting `selectFile()` and how do I fix this so that it will wait for all the files to finish uploading before submitting the form?

Comment: Does the `.catch(err => { console.log(err)  })` in your `selectFile` log an error? Or is any other error logged?

Comment: @t.niese thanks, i cant see any errors in the console... just the XHR post requests when a file is posted (using firefox)

Comment: Another thing. If you post code here, then make a copy and past of the actual code that results in the problem. `return this.$axios.post('/api/post', FormFile))` results in a syntax error, so the code would not even run. If this is your actual code, and you use some bundler, then the building/compositing of the script might already fail due to that and you still might execute some earlier version of your code.

Comment: @t.niese yes you're correct, I was removing my development comment when copying and pasting so an extra bracket appeared. just updated so its correct

Comment: Having a close look i think it might be `@change="selectFile('add')"`. Based on the code you do the upload on the change event, and then call `selectFile` once again on the `sendForm`. This does not make sense, at least not based on the shown code, where both `selectFile('add') ` and  `selectFile()` would result in file uploads.

Comment: @t.niese thanks, I don't want to initiate another upload of the files on `sendForm()`.  All `sendForm()` does is post text elements from my form separately - the files should already have been taken care of by `selectFile()` and `uploadFile()`. I updated the `sendForm()` code to show what `FormBody` has

Comment: Ok, but you have `await this.selectFile();`  in your `async sendForm()` and due to that you do - at least given the shown code - do another upload. You seem to have a logical misconception there.

Comment: @t.niese I have added the code showing what adding to the array of files does in `selectFile()`. If I select 3 files, and while they are uploading I hit the submit form button, then only 3 files still get uploaded (not 6). Its just that that the `FormBody` form data gets submitted as soon as the first of the 3 files is uploaded. I added the logic to selectFile() to show why that is the case because there is metainfo on each file to say if it `isUploading` or `isUploaded`

Comment: With that now shown code it becomes more clear why it does not work. But you don't show where you set `isUploading` to `true`.

Comment: @t.niese I set it in `uploadFile()` in the response back from `axios`. I added the code to show it. I think this has been a lesson in not to omit code from a question for the sake of brevity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `@change="selectFile('add')"` you add the files to `this.$refs.PostFiles` and initiate an upload. And there you do `this.Form.PostFiles[FileIndex][1].isUploading = true;` now the are uploading. And the `this.Form.PostFiles.map(async (file, i) => { … }` holds the Promises returned by `axios`. So you correctly see the `Successfully uploaded all files` once all files are uploaded.

For `sendForm` you call `selectFile` once again and this part of the code is executed another time:

```
return Promise.all(
    this.Form.PostFiles.map(async (file, i) => {
      const File = file[0];
      if (this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].isUploaded == false &&
        this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].isUploading == false) {
        await this.uploadFile({File: File, FileIndex: i});
      }
    })
  )
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Successfully uploaded all files")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

But now `this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].isUploading` is `true` for all of the files. So your code is for that path essentially like this:

```
return Promise.all(
    this.Form.PostFiles.map(async (file, i) => {
      const File = file[0];
    })
  )
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Successfully uploaded all files")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

So `Promise.all` resolves "immediately", not waiting for the uploading files to finish. `Successfully uploaded all files` is logged twice (if you don't reload the page after the form submit), and if now log happens in between you will see it only once with a badge in front of it showing `2`.

What you could do is to save the Promise returned by axioms, with in the object where you store `isUploading`, and use that in the `else` branch of the code in case of the upload being in progress or finished:

```
return Promise.all(
    this.Form.PostFiles.map(async (file, i) => {
      const File = file[0];
      if (this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].isUploaded == false &&
        this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].isUploading == false) {
        this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].uploadPromise = this.uploadFile({File: File, FileIndex: i});
        await this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].uploadPromise;
      } else {
        await this.Form.PostFiles[i][1].uploadPromise;
      }
    })
  )
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Successfully uploaded all files")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

While this solves the problem, it might still not be a good way to combine these to things in one function, as the name `selectFile` is highly misleading about what it does in case of the `submitForm` case.

Comment: You're spot on. As soon as I hit submit, the console.log prints the success message. I am at a loss of how to remedy this :(

Comment: @volumeone I updated the answer with a Q&D solution, but you should consider changing the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it out and it works well. You say I should change the code - I'm not sure what other way to tackle this being a beginner in JS. Is the logic poor?

Comment: @volumeone that out of the scope of SO, and should be asked on code review. Anyhow, the naming of `selectFile` is poor, it does reflect what any of the two cases do (1. adding the files to the list and uploading them, 2. waiting for the files to be uploaded). So this should be difeinitly two functions with proper naming.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to return the promise from the uploadFile into the mapped array:

```
return Promise.all(
        this.Form.PostFiles.map(async (file, i) => {
          const File = file[0];
          return await this.uploadFile({
            File: File
          });
        })
      )
      .then(result => {
        console.log("Successfully uploaded all files")
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
```

Comment: The `async` in front of `(file, i) => {` generates a `Promise` and the `await` in front of `this.uploadFile` will make that Promise to be resolved (or rejected), only if  the promise returned by `this.uploadFile` is resolved/rejected. So those wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks just tried it and same problem - the form submits soon after the first file is uploaded. I just don't understand why the `console.log("successfully uploaded...")` message waits until all promises are resolved, but its telling `sendForm()` that all are resolved soon after only the first promise is resolved.

Comment: Either use `return` or `await` using both only makes sense in really rare use-cases in combination with a try-catch block.

Answer (score -3):

although this does not answer your specific question, you can disable the button for form submit while the upload is on progress and also check if there is any upload is in progress before the form is submitted.

Comment: That *is* what I'm trying to do... preventing form submission until the `selectFile()` promises resolve.

Comment: you do not need async in sendform. you can wrap the `this.$axios.post('/api/post', FormBody)` inside the `await this.selectFile().then((response) => {})`

so when the this.selectFile() is finished it will then trigger the axios post request

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either. Just tried it and after the file is uploaded, the form is submitted.